# Person has 1.15 in dimes and quarters. There are 7 coins all together how many of each does she have?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $d$ stands for dimes

Let $q$ stands for quarters

The closest I can get is $10d + 25q = 115$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $3$ quarters, $4$ dimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nice start. You have the additional information that there are 7 coins altogether. Thus the second equation is $d+q=7$. Soving this equation for $d$ gives $d=7-q$. Now you  put the term for $d$ into your equation.

$$ 10\cdot (7-q) + 25q = 115$$

Solve this equation for $q$.

Comment: Thanks q=3 and so with the 4 other coins those have to be dimes thanks!

Comment: @Yohello1 Yes, that´s right.